# Concepts on MVP with DDD

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, mvp

I recently started doing web dev in C# and I am confused about MVP pattern with the concept of Domain Driven Design.

I was told by one of the seniors that the application is separated into 5 different layers.  The hierachical structure is like this:  View, Presenter, Service, Repository, Entity.

Here are my understandings for these different layers:

`View:` Representation of data that is being delivered to client

`Presenter:` Codebehind.  Handles client's request and sends info to service

`Serivce:` Business logic layer.  Manipulates data.

`Repo:`  Not exactly sure what it does.

`Entity:` An unique object in the domain, and no two objects are ever the same unless they have the same identity (attributes)

So, are my descriptions correct?  Can someone elaborate on that?  Also, what does the Repo layer do?  Does it handle db transaction?

This might not be purely MVP pattern but it seems like this is the state of the application and I am new to all these concepts.  It would be great if someone can explain it to me in simpler terms.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a flew conflicts in my experience.

- View - The actual page that renders data. The code-behind will implement the Interface required for the View.
- Presenter - No, not the code-behind. The code-behind will instantiate a Presenter. The code-behind implements the View interface, and instantiates a Presenter (and generally passes itself along), like so:

  ```
  public class CodeBehindPage : System.Web.UI.Page, IViewInterface {
      private Presenter myPresenter;

      public CodeBehindPage() {
          myPresenter = new Presenter(this); // Presenter will require IViewInterface
      }
  }
  ```
- Service - Correct.
- Repository - Correct, it handles database transactions (loading/saving/etc).
- Entity - Correct. Entities are Database objects.

Comment: If you're taking a DDD approach, the Repository does not handle transactions in a business sense.  It may need transactions to maintain invariants in the database for an aggregate root and its contained entities.  Transactions across aggregate roots would be handled by a UnitOfWork.

Answer (score 1):

I don't prefer to combine MVP design pattern with N-Tier Architecture. What you have described is more likely about N-Tier Architecture. N-Tier is an architecture that creates tier between logics.

Mainly there are 3 logics, presentation logic (UI specific logic such as calculating height or width of a control), business logic (data manipulation, validation, etc) and data access (CRUD operation).

MVP design pattern itself only consist of Model, View and Presenter. The view and presenter, in N-Tier architecture is considered as presentation logic. Model is too general in N-Tier, it can include both business logic and data access. MVP are a design where the view is communicating with the code behind via event-driven. As example is Asp.Net and C# Winform. Another good design pattern is MVC which is used in ASP.Net MVC.

Now speaking of your understandings of layers:

- View is the UI. In Asp.Net it is .aspx file. It is considered as Presentation Logic Layer in N-Tier
- Presenter is the code behind. In Asp.Net it is .aspx.cs file. It is considered as Presentation Logic Layer in N-Tier
- Service is good, it is considered as Business Logic Layer in N-Tier
- Repository is data access. Its main purpose is to communicate with the data storage. It can be Xml, Flat file, CSV or commonly database. It is considered as Data Access Layer in N-Tier
- Entity is an object, which purpose is modelling the data, and will be passed between the layer. There is also a principle of POCO, where your Entity should be made as simple as you can (only consist of Properties). Its main purpose so that your Entities can be used in any kind of layers.

Domain Driven Design itself is another concept. It is a concept of designing the application regarding to the business process requirement. Not based on data which is usually be done by most programmer.